# What is the best practice to use multiple layouts in one Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android

I have a fragment for user registration in that fragment's XML, I have a fixed header and a footer. The header consists of steps for showing the current progress or number of the visible fragment. The footer consist of two buttons for next and back, when I click on next button I want to show the second layout of the registration form and change the colour of the header step so that user can check that he has completed one step and is on the second step, and back button appears because I'm on the second layout. When the user finishes entering all the fields I want to check for validations like email patters is correct, password pattern is correct etc, then send all that form data to the server for user registration. My Question is what is the best practice to do such thing, should I use one fragment and in that fragment I include all the layouts and play with the visibility of the layouts, like if i press the next button the second layout gets visible and first gets gone but the data filled by the user must not get lost because i want that data to get validated and send to server. Or i should make a MainActivity in that main activity i call all the three fragments on button click like if I press the next button the second fragment replaces the first. But again the question is if I go with the activity containing multiple fragments method what will happen to the data of the fragments when user will click on next and back button?

I know it's a long summary of my question but I want to know what's the best practice to do in such cases.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: u can create multiple fragments and replace fragment on click of a button. layout visible and invisible is not the proper way.

Comment: The second approach of using multiple fragments is best as per my view. About what will happen in next back click- You can validate data or save in some common object on each next or back click.

Comment: Maybe you can save user input to a preference file, so the method you mentioned is suitable for use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragments within a viewpager. This will also additionally give you the dots at the bottom visualizing what page and how many pages in total.

[read more about viewpager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide)

Comment: sorry, pagenation with dots is not actually default functionality of the viewpager, but you can easily connect it to your progress in the header/footer.